# Can not start a instance in multipass

Tags: macbook-pro, multipass

When I install multipass at macos 13.2.1, and then exec `multipass launch` to create and start a instance.I get a error:

```
launch failed: The following errors occurred:
Instance stopped while starting.
```

At the multipass.log, I find some error level info:

```
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 2 bit: 8 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 2 bit: 22 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 2 bit: 25 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 4 bit: 12 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 4 bit: 20 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.073] [error] [boss-pelican] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 3 bit: 13 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-26T15:13:27.074] [error] [boss-pelican] kexec: failed to load kernel /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/boss-pelican/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-generic
```

It is worth noting that this is not first can not run, I uninstall multipass at a moment ago. Then I install it again, it can not work.
**So what should I do can let me instance run?**
Please help me everybody in forum, Tks.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You've mentioned nothing yet on-topic for this site, including a non-Ubuntu OS*